# What was the significance of the alien letting the scientist in glasses go in Battleship?

Tags: battleship

In the 2012 movie *Battleship* there is a scene where an alien captures a scientist that has infiltrated an  alien installation with the intent of sabotaging their efforts, and appears to scan his retina.

This has been established as a "thing" that the aliens do. Though the exact reason is never established on screen through dialog or other forms of explicit exposition.

Usually, this action precedes an alien deciding on whether to kill or ignore a person.

The scientists glasses appear to interfere with the process as even though he is clearly a threat to the aliens mission (Having infiltrated a sensitive mission area), the alien lets him go in a similar manner to unarmed civilians and bystanders.

Can the significance of this scene be established, or the relevance to the plot?

Comment: I was forgetting about the children.

Answer (score 1):

> ...in every other instance of this happening in the movie the alien kills the person involved.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. There are numerous instances in the movie where peoples faces are scanned and are left alive and unharmed. The aliens seem to be mission oriented in destroying essential equipment in most cases rather than random killing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was more thinking in relations to the soldiers, I've edited the question to take this into account.

Comment: You should not change questions that invalidate answers already given. If you still have questions specifically regarding military personnel you should ask a NEW question.

Comment: And have it deleted by the moderators for being too similar to the original.

Comment: No reason why it should be closed or deleted since it's asking a separate and specific question... just make sure you refer to the original and say why you are aksing something more specific.

Comment: This is what typically happens to me